# How do I create wp-cron job and access the data?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

This is my first time trying to write a cron job, so I need some assistance.

I have a PHP function that sorts a bunch of stuff into date order. I want it to run once a day in the background, instead of when the user logs in as a session variable.

I have two questions - how do I create the cron job to call the function, and then what should I do with the sorted array (and how can I access it later)?

Answer (score 0):

This is function to schedule cron job in wordpress:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

You have to store the sorted array in some way, for example serialize it and save in db or file, then you can read it. This only makes sense if the query is very heavy.

Enjoy your code!